# Problems with accents in Java at Runtime

Tags: java, runtime

I'm from spain and I have developed a new application with Netbeans. Some of the tags of the aplicacion uses spanish accents an ñ, when I run the application in netbeans every thing is OK, but when I run int from command line with the virtual machine (java myapplication) all the special characters are not shown in the right way, only strange symbols.

How can I set the right characters man on runtime?

Thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Windows, the Windows Terminal doesn't support Unicode, so that is likely why things are failing. You'll need to use a third-party terminal program that supports unicode.

Answer (score 0):

If your terminal supports unicode,

```
System.out.println("\u00D1");
System.out.println("\u00F1");
```

For Windows cmd, take a look at : http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com.es/2009/04/java-unicode-on-windows-command-line.html